# Multiple PrimeNg table checkbox issue

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am trying to implement multiple `tables` using `PrimeNg` in my Angular application. Each table has a `checkbox` in the first column that allows the user to select rows. The tables are nested within different `components`: component `Y` is inside component `X`, and there can be multiple instances of component `Y` within component `X`.

I encountered an issue when trying to uncheck all selected rows from the `X` component. The unchecking functionality works correctly for the first table, but not for subsequent tables. To demonstrate the issue, I created a Plunker that replicates the problem.

Here's the link to the Plunker: [Plunker Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablevirtualscroll-demo-oz6mnq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnew%2Fnew.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fnew%2Fnew.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

If you select some checkboxes in the second table and then click the button located above the table to uncheck them, you'll notice that although the object is reset in the console, the checkbox remains checked. However, this problem doesn't occur in the first table.

I suspect that I might be overlooking some basic Angular concepts or checks that need to be implemented. I would appreciate any help or guidance in resolving this issue.

Comment: There are no checkboxes at that link